# Color of the last point in the ListLinePlot

Tags: plotting, marker

I have got the following data structure:

```
test = {RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{3, 8}], 12], 
  RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{3, 8}], 12], 
  RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{3, 8}], 12], 
  RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{3, 8}], 12], 
  RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{3, 8}], 12], 
  RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{3, 8}], 12], 
  RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{3, 8}], 12], 
  RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{3, 8}], 12], 
  RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{3, 8}], 12]}
```

Then, I create the plots for each of the subsets by:

```
Table[ListLinePlot[{test[[n]]}, PlotMarkers -> Automatic], {n, 1, 9}]
```

Which gives me the following:
[image]

Is there a way how I could label the last point in each plot? Or how to make it Red for example?

Comment: ``Table[Show[ListLinePlot[test[[n]], PlotMarkers -> Automatic], ListPlot[{{Length@test[[n]], test[[n, -1]]}}, PlotMarkers -> Automatic, PlotStyle -> Red]], {n, 1, 9}]`` to make it red. Not sure what kind of labelling you want, perhaps: ``Table[Show[ListLinePlot[test[[n]], PlotMarkers -> Automatic], ListPlot[Labeled[{{Length@test[[n]], test[[n, -1]]}}, "Last point", Left], PlotMarkers -> Automatic, PlotStyle -> Red]], {n, 1, 9}]``

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SeedRandom[1]
test = RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{3, 8}], {9, 12}];
```

You can transform lists in `test` into lists of pairs by adding x-coordinates using `MapIndexed`:

```
test2 = MapIndexed[{Last@#2, #} &, test, {2}];

labels = "LBL " <> ToString @ # & /@ Range[Length @ test2];
```

Plot `test[[i]]` together with the last element of `test[[i]]` using `Callout` to attach a label to it:

```
Table[ListLinePlot[{test2[[i]], {Callout[test2[[i, -1]], labels[[i]], Above]}}, 
   PlotMarkers -> Automatic, 
   PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Red}, 
   PlotRangeClipping -> False, 
   ImagePadding -> 10],
 {i, Length @ test2}]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can use `Table` to get the lists of pairs:

```
test3 = Table[{j, test[[i, j]]}, {i, 9}, {j, 12}];

test3 == test2
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Comment: May I ask, why the ```test2``` step was necessary?

Comment: @Syed, it is not necessary. I find adding explicit horizontal coordinates  more convenient to `ListPlot/ListLinePlot` multiple datasets  with differing x coordinates.

Comment: Thank you, guys!